# redirect from CAS login page when user is already logged in

Tags: java, cas

We use CAS for authentication.  The scenarios is as follows:

User attempts to access site www.awesomesite.com/coolthings.

If user has not logged in yet they are taken to www.awesomesite.com/login which is actually CAS login.
User logs in and is taken to site they tried to get to, in this case www.awesomsite.com/coolthings.

Now, if the user goes to www.awesomesite.com/login  when they are logged in, I would like to redirect them to a home page.  What actually happens is they go to the login page, CAS responds that they are logged in, but they aren't redirected anywhere because they put they are already at the url.  So they just sit on an empty page.  Is there a parameter I can set in the AutenticationFilter I can use to redirect from login if they're already logged in

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any out-of-the box way to do that, I think you need to compute a default CAS service (*www.awesomesite.com/coolthings*) if no service is defined. I recommend to do that by overriding the **initialFlowSetupAction** (in the login-webflow.xml file).